functional equation on the set of real numbers
I have a functional equation as follows
find $f:R\to R$ satisfy: $f(x+f(xy))=f(x)+xf(y)$ for all real numbers x,y
I don't see the feasibility to prove this is an injective function or this is a Surjection function
In the process of proving it, I found it $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$

$x=y=-1$ we have $f(f(1)-1)=0$. let $a=f(1)-1$ so $f(a)=0$

$x=a,y=1$ we have $af(1)=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $a=0$ (that mean $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$) or $f(1)=0$

$x=y=0$ we have $f(f(0))=0$

$y=0$ we have $f(x+f(0))=f(x)+xf(0)$, $x=f(0)$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(2f(0))=f(0)+f^2(0)$

$x=f(0),y=1$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(2f(0))=f(0)+f(0)f(1)$


$\Rightarrow$ $f(0)=0$ or $f(1)=f(0)$
From the above data, we deduce the above two things
I've been thinking for a long time but still can't find it. Please give me your suggestions
thanks very much

The function which is identically $0$ satisfies this.

See art of problem solving for all solutions.

@DietrichBurde oh thanks you so much
